# Banco de dados sobrecarrega ao deletar linhas com relacionamentos?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, tabela-html, relacionamento

Boa tarde a todos!

Estou com uma dúvida, e gostaria de opiniões a repeito.

Estou construindo um sistema em **php** + **laravel**.

Tenho relacionamentos entre tabelas, por ex: `Users->Roles`.

> Supõe-se que existam **10.000** *users* cadastrados com a `Role == Admin`.
>   Se eu excluo a ***Role Admin***, o sistema teoricamente teria de excluir **10.000** linhas da tabela `role_users` pois a **Role Admin** deixará de existir.

Isso geraria **10.000** queries?
Sobrecarregaria o BD?

Abraços

Comment: `Admin` é um é um valor pertencente a `Roles` e `Users` tem uma **FK** de `Roles`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em qualquer sistema relacional, se você tiver uma relação que indica que a deleção do elemento pai remove os elementos filhos em cascata, a deleção de um único elemento pai e todos os seus filhos ocorrerá em uma única query.

Se isso sobrecarregará ou não o banco depende do fluxo da remoção em cascata e do tamanho da massa de dados a apagar. Seus registros de usuários podem ter outros relacionamentos com seus próprios filhos, que também podem ser removidos em cascata, por exemplo. Mas em geral, remover é rápido. Principalmente se a relação entre os elementos tiver indexação na coluna do lado "filho" do relacionamento.

O peso todo fica no processamento do banco de dados. Pra aplicação, uma única query em uma única conexão é executada.

Answer (score 1):

Ele vai gerar sim querys para deletar e vai gerar um trabalho extra para levantar todos os lugares que devem ser deletados juntos.
Mas essa abordagem de on delete cascade que faz ele dropar as chaves associadas ainda assim é mais rápida que se você pedir para fazer 10mil deletes.

Se vai sobrecarregar não da para dizer, vai depender muito da sua maquina.
Mas é sempre interessante criar indexes para as chaves de todas as tabelas associadas.
Leitura complementar: http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/04/12/explicit-sql-delete-vs-on-delete-cascade/